# Rails with AngularJS application.js refused MIME type ('text/html')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, asset-pipeline, mime, production-environment

I followed this tutorial: https://thinkster.io/angular-rails/ to implement rails along with AngularJS.

I have an application.html.erb file, where I use this line:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

to include the js asset pipeline.

On development environment, it works fine. When I switch to production the following error is shown:

> Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/javascripts/application.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

I tried precompiling the application.js file using this line

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( application.js )
```

but it didn't work. Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and I figured out that it was due to a routing error. I had a catch-all route in my routes.rb file:

```
root 'home#index', anchor: false
```

Rails was serving the HTML page in that route instead of serving the assets, which resulted in the MIME error.

I fixed it by replacing the code in the routes.rb file with a pattern that would not catch the asset requests:

```
root 'home#index'
get ':path', to: 'home#index', format: false
```

You also may need to serve static assets depending on your web server configuration (for me this was in config/environments/staging.rb):

```
config.serve_static_files = true
```

Hope this helps!